# Get multiple random rows with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```
Criteria crit=getSession().createCriteria(Student.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.like("studentName", "John" )));  
int count=crit.list().size();
int index=new Random().nextInt(count);
crit.setFirstResult(index).setMaxResults(3);
```

This code returns only the first result as random and the next three consecutive rows (not random). I would like to obtain 3 random rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to define an auto-incremented numeric ID to the Student entity, then, randomly get 3 values (between the lowest ID and the greatest ID) so that you could use a criterion such as :

```
Restrictions.in("id", {randomVal1, randomVal2, randomVal3})
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment                                                                                                                                  I think its better to go with hql and use  order by rand()